# Unity on Linux dosen't show editor panels

Tags: unity, linux

I've recently installed Unity Hub on my Kubuntu 22.04 installation with the [unofficial Appimage](https://gitlab.com/Megver83/unityhub-appimage/-/releases). I have tried this with the `unityhub` package too, and still have the same problem.

It's pretty simple; when I try to open something like "edit > preferences" in the Unity editor, it doesn't show up. The "preferences" panel is there, because going to Window > Panels shows me it's there, just clicking it does nothing.

I have tried to change the Layout to default, didn't do anything.

I have tried using a different Unity editor version, same problem.

When I had a fresh reboot, I opened up the project settings; that worked, and the shortcuts panel also showed up, but the preferences window did not and after that project settings also didn't show up (like the other panels, it exists, but I can't see it).

I have no idea what the problem is; desktop environment? compositor? NVIDIA settings? It seems to work for other people, as I didn't find anything related to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. The panels are out of the screen, that's why I can't see them.

I you use Kubuntu, you can hold your mouse to the top left corner of your screen and see all open windows. Select the "preference" Window e.g. and press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd> to select your screen.

It may be because I have a dual screen setup, but I don't know why the screens start in limbo.